# Developing on Magento

Tags: magento, magento2

I have no idea how to develop custom pages on the Magento CMS. I am able to create custom page templates using WordPress though.

Can I carry over any WordPress web development knowledge to develop custom pages on Magento?
I am trying to get an idea of how difficult it might be to develop on a different framework.

I have not tried anything yet. Only wanting to get idea of difficulty level.

Comment: you can put your html in the custom pages

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Magento docs to know how to add a page in Magwnto.
Please refer: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/cms/page-create.html

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Please put the content in the answer itself and only add links for support of the content you've created.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 and 2 work on theming structure - each page is developed using a group of files - `.xml` for structure and calling elements and `.phtml` to further display elements. All the logic and processing is done in `.php`.

I do believe your WP knowledge would be useful as it's both written in OO PHP. Magento dev docs are a great place to start as it's a step by step guide. Also, there are tons of tutorials online by big communities and good developers.

Magento is a bigger system so it does take more time to grasp, but it's not hard. Good luck!